# Angular Application With Google Charts Getting Struck While Going To New Route

Tags: angular7, jhipster, google-visualization, angular7-router

I have integrated google charts in my angular7 application by the reference of [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart). But If I go from charts page to new page via routing application responding very late(Feeling application got struck for few seconds).

My angular application was JHipster application.

Comment: Have you looked at network tab in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Yes, I observed loader.js, jsapi_compiled_format_module.js and ...etc are loading for first time, how can I make it load at application load time?

Comment: If ChartWrapper is used rather than the loader specifying the packages to load, then the ChartWrapper will trigger a dynamic loading. So figure out how to load the packages with the loader.